# qsort not sorting and strange output

Tags: c, qsort

so I'm using C, I cant seem to get this to work right. It's an array of pointers to structs which contain some contact info. I can't seem to get the qsort to sort correctly. 
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 20
#define ELEMENTS 50

int sortZips(const void *a, const void *b);

typedef struct contactInfo {
char name[MAX];
char street[MAX];
char cityState[MAX];
char zipCode[MAX];
} contacts;


int main() {
int i = 0;
contacts **contactArray = malloc(ELEMENTS * sizeof(contacts *));     

/*  allocate array  */
for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
    contactArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(contacts));
}
/*  populate array  */
for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
    fgets(contactArray[i]->name,MAX,stdin);
    fgets(contactArray[i]->street,MAX,stdin);
    fgets(contactArray[i]->cityState,MAX,stdin);
    fgets(contactArray[i]->zipCode,MAX,stdin);

    printf("%s", contactArray[i]->name);
    printf("%s", contactArray[i]->street);
    printf("%s", contactArray[i]->cityState);
    printf("%s", contactArray[i]->zipCode);

}
printf("\n");


/*  qsort((void *)contactArray, ELEMENTS, sizeof(contacts *), sortZips);  */


for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
    fputs(contactArray[i]->name,stdout);
    fputs(contactArray[i]->street,stdout);
    fputs(contactArray[i]->cityState,stdout);
    fputs(contactArray[i]->zipCode,stdout);
}


}


/*  sortZips() sort function for qsort  */

int sortZips(const void *a, const void *b) {

const contacts *ia = *(contacts **)a;
const contacts *ib = *(contacts **)b;
return strcmp(ia->zipCode, ib->zipCode);



}
```

The output is printing the addresses (I have 50 in an input file) and then some random characters, like a huge block of them, then the sorted list after that which is messed up and not sorted right.

Please any help would be appreciated. I need to learn what's wrong here and why. 
Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule: always check input functions - in this case, `fgets()`.  You don't know whether everything is working correctly or not if you do not check.

Second: use `enum` in preference to `#define` in general.

With the check for early EOF in place, your code sorted my sample data (6 rows) cleanly.  It also compiled cleanly - which is very unusual (that's a compliment; I use stringent warnings and even my code seldom compiles cleanly the first time).  My amended version of your code is very similar to yours:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int num;
    contacts **contactArray = malloc(ELEMENTS * sizeof(contacts *));

    /*  allocate array  */
    for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
        contactArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(contacts));

    /*  populate array  */
    for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        if (fgets(contactArray[i]->name,MAX,stdin) == 0 ||
            fgets(contactArray[i]->street,MAX,stdin) == 0 ||
            fgets(contactArray[i]->cityState,MAX,stdin) == 0 ||
            fgets(contactArray[i]->zipCode,MAX,stdin) == 0)
            break;
        printf("%s", contactArray[i]->name);
        printf("%s", contactArray[i]->street);
        printf("%s", contactArray[i]->cityState);
        printf("%s", contactArray[i]->zipCode);
    }
    printf("\n");
    num = i;

    qsort(contactArray, num, sizeof(contacts *), sortZips);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        fputs(contactArray[i]->name,stdout);
        fputs(contactArray[i]->street,stdout);
        fputs(contactArray[i]->cityState,stdout);
        fputs(contactArray[i]->zipCode,stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The data I used was trivial repetitions of sets of 4 lines like this:

```
First LastName7
7 Some Street
City, CA
95437
```

---

Note that the 'error checking' I do in the input is the bare minimum that 'works'.  If you get an over-long line in the input, one field will not contain a newline, and the next will contain the next section of the input line (possibly all the rest, possibly not - it depends on how badly overlong the line is).

Comment: yea I see that I should have focused on the input function to see where the mess is starting. I was thinking about the sort and whether I was correctly accessing members of the struct. Which was kind of confusing me. I never used qsort before this and I had some trouble grasping the idea of passing in void * to the sorting function.

Answer (score 0):

If your addresses are printing out rubbish at the end, then it's almost certainly because you haven't allocated enough space for them. Twenty characters is a little on the low side for addresses.

What's probably happening is that you have an address like:

```
14237 Verylongstreetname Avenue
```

and, when you do `fgets (street,20,stdin);`, only `14237 Verylongstree` will be read (19 characters, leaving space for the null terminator).

And, here's the crux: the file pointer will still be pointing at the `tname Avenue` bit so that, when you try to read the `cityState`, you'll get that. And, when you try to read the `zipCode`, you'll get the `cityState` line, effectively stuffing up your sorting.

Comment: ok thank you for responding, but there was one really dumb thing on my part that I didn't realize! and it solved the issue, the input file did NOT have 50 input values for contacts. There was 18, setting 'ELEMENTS' to 18 solves the issue, I also boosted 'MAX' to 40, just in case.  So I think what happened is that I allocated 50 elements to 'contactArray' and put 18 elements of data and it just put random crap in the rest and printed that out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have enough space. Because you are using fgets and your size of MAX, the strings should be cut to fit and have a terminating NUL at the end.

Two things that might be messing it up:

- fgets will read from where it stopped reading if the line is too long. That will result in an address of "This is too long so", " it will be cut\n". And then the rest of the input will be all over the place.
- If you do not have enough input to fill ELEMENTS items then you'll get whatever random data was in the malloc'd memory. If you were to use `calloc` instead, it would zero the memory for you. Although the better idea would be to use a counter of how many items were actually read, instead of assuming there will be ELEMENTS items.